# Is SHA1 and SHA256 associative?

Tags: math, hash, sha1, sha256, hash-function

Let x be a variable over which we intend to use the hash function.

I want to know if `SHA256(SHA1(x))` is equal to `SHA1(SHA256(x))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this tool: http://www.sha1-online.com/ and found out this wont be associative.

Example

```
SHA256(SHA1("156")) = e8fed31bea496eb025ac3b1c09e69da975cfd1faf446fbef26cbfa265f5285e7
SHA1(SHA256("156")) = b2e10b1aec52c913d4f77060af3232105fc6d115
```

Even the hash function length differs, so there is no question of equality.

Comment: Not overtly theoretical, but very compelling (-: